# How to check if flashlight is turned on in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm completely a newbie in android development and I'm trying to check the status of camera flash light is turned on or off.

Can someone tell me if it's possible, any sample piece of code will be helpful to understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131361/how-to-detect-whether-the-flashlight-is-on-or-off

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect whether the flashlight is on or off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131361/how-to-detect-whether-the-flashlight-is-on-or-off)